# Unit test http context in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, httpclient, karma-jasmine, httpcontext

I have this API call in my service

```
import { HttpContext } from '@angular/common/http';
export const SET_INVALID_TOKEN = new HttpContextToken(() => false);
...
    postSomething() {
        this.httpClient.post<MyModel>(`${this.API_SERVER_ADDRESS}/...`, {...}, { context: new HttpContext().set(SET_INVALID_TOKEN, true) })
    }
```

The reason I am using this context is to debug invalid token cases to my interceptors. You can find more information about this on [this article](https://dev.to/angular/what-the-heck-is-httpcontext-in-angular-4n3c). I should mention here that this context is used ONLY for debugging purposes. The point is that it should never be forgotten at a production stage.

Here is my unit test for the api call

```
fit('should ...', (done: DoneFn) => {
    let httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    let service = TestBed.get(AnalysisAPIService);
    service.postSomething().subscribe(
        analyses => {
            ...
            done()
        },
        done.fail
    )
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(service["API_SERVER_ADDRESS"] + "/...");
    console.log(req.request.context.keys())
    req.flush(AnalysisMock.mockAnalysesResponse)// allows to use the dummy data
    
});
```

**PROBLEM**

The `req.request.context.keys()` is an empty object

**QUESTION**

how can I check for my unit test if there is an HttpContext set?

Comment: You don't seem to provide your interceptor to your tests. Could you confirm that ?

Comment: Also, if you want to test that your interceptor works, the test should be done in the interceptor, not in the service using it.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I will not forget this context to my source code, because I use it ONLY for debugging. So, this should never go like this to the production

Comment: I confirm I do not provide my interceptors to my tests, but I am not sure this is relevant, but maybe it is

Comment: No forget this, if you only want to test the context is given. I thought you wanted to see if the http call is made completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on the http mock, you can use spies

```js
const spy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(EMPTY));

service['httpClient'].post = spy;

service.postSomething();

expect(spy.calls.argsFor(1)[1].context instanceof HttpContext).toBeTrue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a callback to `HttpTestingController.expectOne` and make assertions on the request in the callback function.

Either by returning true/false for if the request meets your conditions:

```
const req = httpController.expectOne((r) => {
  return r.context.get(SET_INVALID_TOKEN);
});
req.flush(mockResponse);
```

or using explicit expectations (not sure if this is recommended but I like this more):

```
const req = httpController.expectOne((r) => {
  expect(r.context.url).toEqual("https://localhost:3000/blah");
  expect(r.context.get(SET_INVALID_TOKEN).toBeFalse();
  expect(r.headers.get("my-header").toEqual("my-header-value");
  return true;
});
req.flush(mockResponse);
```